# How to execute a block of code ONLY after another block of code is executed

Tags: swift, closures, grand-central-dispatch

Under the button `Male`, I have two completion handlers. For some reason, the second handler runs simultaneously with the first completion handler. I'am very unfamiliar with Grand Central Dispatch (have deleted my failed attempts at doing so) but I'm looking to set this up using GCD in a way that ONLY once the first completion handler is executed, then execute the second handler.

```
@IBAction func Male(sender: AnyObject) {

 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(self.userdefaults.objectForKey("FBid") as! String).child("anonymous chatting").child("Males").child("Non-Chatting").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot2: FIRDataSnapshot!) in

                self.nonChatting = Int(snapshot2.childrenCount)

                print("yobitch\(self.nonChatting)")

                }, withCancelBlock: nil)

//^^^^^^^^^^^^EXECUTE THIS COMPLETION HANDLER FIRST            

     FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(self.userdefaults.objectForKey("FBid") as! String).child("anonymous chatting").child("Males").child("Non-Chatting").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

               if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                    if self.Malecount < self.listofMaleFriends.count {
                        self.idArray.append(dictionary)
                        self.Malecount += 1}
        }

               self.loopCount += 1
                if self.loopCount == self.listofMaleFriends.count-(self.matchingLoopCount) {
                self.loopCount = 0
                self.matchingLoopCount += 1
                    if self.idArray.count == self.listofMaleFriends.count-(self.Othercount){
                        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.idArray.count)))
                        if self.idArray.isEmpty{
                        }
                        else{

                            let Dictionaire = self.idArray[randomNumber] as! [String: AnyObject]
                            let id = Dictionaire["id"] as! String
                            let gender = Dictionaire["gender"] as! String
                            let name = Dictionaire["name"] as! String
                            self.idArray.removeAtIndex(randomNumber)
                            self.Othercount += 1   /* Reduces Male Count*/

                let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL("https://game-of-chats-ce897.firebaseio.com/").child("users").child(self.userdefaults.objectForKey("FBid") as! String).child("anonymous chatting").child("Males").child("Chatting").child(id)
                let refout = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL("https://game-of-chats-ce897.firebaseio.com/").child("users").child(self.userdefaults.objectForKey("FBid") as! String).child("anonymous chatting").child("Males").child("Non-Chatting").child(id)
                ref.setValue(["id": id, "gender": gender, "name": name])
                refout.removeValue()

                  //let user = User()
                  //  user.id = self.friendId
                   // user.name = self.friendName
                   // showChatControllerForUser(user)
                   self.user.id = Dictionaire["id"] as! String
                    self.user.name = Dictionaire["name"] as! String
                    //let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

                   // self.(chatLogController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatLogController, animated: true)
                self.showChatControllerForUser()

                        }}}

            }, withCancelBlock: nil)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [dispatch_group](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25) to synchronise the two tasks.

1. Create a dispatch group using `dispatch_group_create()`.
2. For each task, call `dispatch_group_enter()`.
3. When the task completes, call `dispatch_group_leave()`.
4. Wait for the tasks to complete by calling `dispatch_group_notify()`.

Example:

```
let node = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(self.userdefaults.objectForKey("FBid") as! String).child("anonymous chatting").child("Males").child("Non-Chatting")

let group = dispatch_group_create()

// Second handler
dispatch_group_enter(group)

node.observeEventType(.Value, 
    withBlock: { (snapshot2: FIRDataSnapshot!) in
        // Handle event...
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }, 
    withCancelBlock: nil
)

// First handler
dispatch_group_enter(group)

node.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, 
    withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        // Handle event
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }
    withCancelBlock: nil
)


dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.showChatControllerForUser()
}
```

Tip: Remove the event observers once they're handled, otherwise you will just keep retaining a new reference each time the `IBAction` is called.